# Jquery not working on node edit page

Tags: javascript

Added jquery library, it works fine, but when i click on node edit, jquery does not work for this page. I need to style some inputs inside this edit page. I am using theme zen.
For example i want to change color of edit-title

```
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#edit-title').css('color', 'red');

  });
})(jQuery);
```

not working. Its loaded i see in firebug. But any code does not work(only inside edit or admin menus).

Comment: What do you mean by added jquery library. It is already included in the Drupal install. Did you want to update the library ?? if so the correct way of doing it is using http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update

Comment: added script not library sorry

Comment: Try using the `jQuery` over the `$` syntax. In other words, `jQuery(document).ready(function() { jQuery('#edit-title')` and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the firebug(any) console, try `jQuery('#edit-title').css('color', 'red');` it should work or something with the css is wrong.

For Drupal you're really supposed to use something like this to do on document load:

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.exampleModule = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $('.example', context).click(function () {
        $(this).next('ul').toggle('show');
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Check out [Managing JavaScript in Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/node/756722), and search for "behaviors".

@ krister.. The code is a function where the `$` variable is `jQuery`. So in most languages you create function and declare variables that you want passed into it. Well in JavaScript you can create that in one line.

```
function some_function(tmpVar){ alert(tmpVar); }
some_function("Woot!");

You can wrap the function side in ()s and it still works
( some_function )("Woot!");

Now you can put an anonymous function block instead of some_function

( function(tmpVar){ alert(tmpVar); } )("Woot!");
```

and finally the jQuery

```
(function($){... the $ = jQuery ...})(jQuery);
```